# Window isn't active when opening powerpoint file with pywin32

Tags: python, ms-office, powerpoint, pywin32, win32com

I tried to open an existing file of powerpoint with pywin32 however this code couldn't do window active.
Do you have any ideas for this problem ?

```
import win32com.client

file_name = r'your file path\your file name.pptx'
Application = None

try:

  Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
  Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(file_name)
  Application.Activate()
  Application.Visible = True

             *
             *
         some codes
             *
             *

except Exception as e:
  print(e)
finally:
  Application.Quit()
```

I tried to change the position of Application.Activate() and Application.Visible = True however these were the same result.